# Copying and pasting in jqgrid wipes out text and displays input string

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Having a strange problem with jqGrid in-cell edit. If I click into a row (a text field) it selects the cell.  Then when I right click to copy it wipes out my text and inserts the html input string like:

This problem happens even when I click into an empty cell and right click. See image below.

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Can't add image here.  Please see:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/dtol-public-site/jq-grid-problem.jpg

Here's the code. I excluded columns that are not an issue.

$("#lineitems").jqGrid({
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'post',
                url: url,
                colNames: ['', 'Description'],
                colModel: [
                            { name: 'LineNum', index: 'linenum', key: true, width: 35, align: 'center' },
                            { name: 'Description', width: 293, editable: true },
                            { name: 'MultiFact', hidden: true }
                        ],
                postData:
                {
                    id: id,
                    type: "M",
                    weight: weight,
                    qty: qty
                },
                gridComplete: function () {
                    colmodel = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel');
                    var ids = jQuery('#lineitems').jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                },
                onSelectRow: function (id) {
                    if (id && id !== lastsel) {
                        $('#lineitems').jqGrid('restoreRow', lastsel);
                        $('#lineitems').jqGrid('editRow', id, true);
                        lastsel = id;
                    }
                },

Comment: Are you sure that this problem is related to jqgrid and not with operating system..

Comment: Update question with jqgrid code

Comment: Please update your questions and in your code exists `restoreRow` in edit line ou edit cell trade for `saverow`.

Comment: OS?  It's a web app.  Tested using Chrome & Safari.  Same result.  I discovered it is not related to copy and paste.  When I click into the editable row the with of the row is selected.  As soon as I press right-click it displays the html input statement as input type="text" id="1_Description" name="Description" role="textbox" style="width: 98%;" I removed the < > brackets as it prevented the code from showing in my post here.

Comment: Unless you share your code as dave asked, we can't really find a solution.

Comment: Here it is.  I excluded all the other rows which are not an issue.